# How to pass a JS variable to a second script without it being accessible or mutable from the console?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, global-variables, private-key

I have two scripts, one to calculate a total for the items in a shopping cart and one to pass the variable to a PayPal API. Is it possible to pass this variable from the shopping cart script to the PayPal script without someone being able to change its value from the console? Otherwise people would be able to determine how much they would like to pay for the items and send the info through to PayPal. Here is my code:

Shopping Cart:

````
```
var total = 0; //Total for all the items in the shopping cart, value is passed off to paypal-buttons.js to complete the checkout.
````

```
// Calculates values items in cart depending on quantity
function addData(clicked_id, quantity) {
  var price = values[clicked_id].price;
  var qty = document.getElementById(quantity).value;
  var lineTotal = price * qty;
  total += lineTotal;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
  addRow(clicked_id, qty, lineTotal);
}
```

PayPal:

```
    paypal.Buttons({
  style: {
    shape: 'rect',
    color: 'gold',
    layout: 'vertical',
    label: 'checkout',

  },
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {

    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          value: total
        }
      }]
    });
  },
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
      alert('Thank you for your order ' + details.payer.name.given_name +   ', your equipment is on its way!');
    });
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

I would like to send the value of 'total' from the shopping cart to PayPal. I might try using obfuscation as a partial solution but I would like it to be more secure then that.

Comment: If the variable can be changed from the console, that means it is in the global scope.  A simple usage of an IIFE could fix that issue.  However, keep in mind, anyone smart enough to use a browser debugger could still get around that.

Comment: Instead of loading multiple scripts you could use [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Comment: Rather than doing client side processing, you should store the basket in any way you like (it doesn't need to be secure) and then POST it to a known **secure** server. This server then makes the request to PayPal to make the payment, after calculating the total price **from the prices stored on the server**. This way, even if the client is making malicious requests, all they can do is buy stuff. You should also make sure to validate that the person is not buying negative numbers of items, because that is an easy way to steal money.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to secure against malicious client-side changes is to switch to a server-side integration for the API calls to set up and capture the payment. Here is a demo pattern of the UI:

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Here is a guide to implementing the necessary v2/orders API calls from your server:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/